# Buttons in vector not responding to custom drawing

Tags: c++, winapi, vector, hwnd

I have a Win32 program in which I have a vector which contains the `HWND` of some buttons which I want to custom draw. I can owner-draw them, but all I want to do is change the background color, so it seems unnecessary to do so. However, they don't seem to change as a result of being custom drawn. They look the same.

I create the buttons like this:

```
#define ID_BUTTON1 40000

std::vector<HWND> ButtonsVector;

for (int i = 0, i > NumButtons, i++) {
    ButtonsVector.push_back(CreateWindowEx(
                NULL,
                L"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
                L"X",      // Button text 
                WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
                x,         // x position 
                y,         // y position (substitute some x and y values for these) 
                20,        // Button width
                20,        // Button height
                hWnd,     // Parent window 
                (HMENU)ID_BUTTON1 + i,       // Unique button ID
                (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
                NULL));
}
```

I use this `WM_NOTIFY` to draw them:

```
HBRUSH hHotBrush;
HBRUSH hDefaultBrush;

case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
            LPNMHDR some_item = (LPNMHDR)lParam;

            if (some_item->idFrom >= ID_BUTTON1 && some_item->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
            {
                LPNMCUSTOMDRAW item = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)some_item;


                if (item->uItemState & CDIS_HOT) //Our mouse is over the button
                {
                    //Select our color when the mouse hovers our button
                    if (hHotBrush == NULL)
                        hHotBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(230, 0, 0));

                    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                    HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                    HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, hHotBrush);

                    RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 5, 5);

                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                    DeleteObject(pen);

                    return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                }

                //Select our color when our button is doing nothing
                if (hDefaultBrush == NULL)
                    hDefaultBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));

                HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, hDefaultBrush);

                RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 5, 5);

                SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                DeleteObject(pen);

                return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
            }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: [Currently, the following controls support custom draw functionality: header, list view, rebar, toolbar, tooltip, trackbar, and tree view. **Custom draw is also supported for button controls if you have an application manifest to ensure that Comctl32.dll version 6 is available.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw) Do you?

Comment: This is also stated in [NM_CUSTOMDRAW (button) notification code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw-button): "*To use this notification code, you must provide a manifest specifying Comclt32.dll version 6.0. For more information on manifests, see [Enabling Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview).*"

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to add a preprocessor directive, and it worked! If you could please post this as an answer so I can accept it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You can [post your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) showing what you found that worked for you.

Comment: Ok, I will do that.

Comment: I can accept it in two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the following line:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version = '6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture = '*' publicKeyToken = '6595b64144ccf1df' language = '*'\"")
```

This makes sure that ComCtrl32.dll version 6 is being used, allowing the custom-drawing of button controls. One thing you have to be careful of, however, is which version of Windows you are targeting for your application, as versions older than XP do not include this version of the dll.